# IE8 problem with jQuery plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer-8

I've developed a plugin that makes characters jump and bounce when moused over in any element that contains text.

[Here is an example](http://www.alexanderdickson.com/projects/jquery/bumpytext/example.html).

It works great in Firefox 3.5, Chrome, Safari 3.1 and IE7 (oddly, but in compatibility mode) but in IE8 it seems the characters disappear as they rise. I've added top padding to the p element, because it looked like they were being hidden from something like `overflow: hidden`, but they appear to rise a bit and then completely disappear, only to reappear on their way down.

Does anyone know what may be causing this?

Thank you very much Stackers!

Comment: I don't have IE8 installed on this machine, but just for the record it works very well in IE6. :-)

Comment: @Roberto - that's a surprise! Thanks for your input.

Comment: I'm up-voting the question for the sheer awesome of the plug-in. I *really like* that! =)

Comment: @ricebowl - glad you like it. I'm pretty sure none of my plugins have ever seen the light of day outside of my projects. Feel free to use it on your site!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setting a line-height should fix it.